# How can I load a JSON file in Brython?

Tags: json, file, brython

I am working on a page with Brython, and one thing I would like to do is load a JSON file on the same server, in the same directory.

How can I do that? `open()`? Something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, here is how I did it.

In my file .bry.

```py
import json

css_file = "static/json/css.json"

j = json.load(open(css_file))

# For debug
console.log(j)
```

Since it is from your HTML page that the execution is done, make sure to start from your .html file and not .py or .bry to search your JSON file.

Also, check if your JSON file has the right structure ;)

Here is my tree structure.

```
|   index.html
|   README.txt
|   unicode.txt
|   
+---static
|   +---assets
|   |       
|   +---css
|   |           
|   +---fonts
|   |                      
|   +---js
|   |         
|   +---json
|   |       css.json
|   |       
|   \---py
|       |   main.bpy
```

Hoping to have helped :D

Comment: This worked for me mostly; one thing I had to do differently was change `console.log` to `print`

Comment: Just posted a first Brython hack at https://cjshayward.com/wizard/. Hope this is the first of many more.